# Short word or phrase meaning "Border and Fill"

Tags: menu, wording

Is there a word or short phrase for "change the border color and fill color of a polygon in a single step"?  I would prefer that the word or phrase not contain any conjunctions.

This word or phrase will go in a "Color..." submenu.  The user will select the polygon(s) to re-color, and then navigate to this menu item.  Thus, the "change the...", "color", "polygon", and "single step" portions of the sentence will be implicit.  So what I really need is a single word or short phrase that means "Outline and Fill" or "Border and Fill".

The "Color..." menu already has choices for "Border...", "Fill...", and "Pen...".  ("Pen" sets the foreground color of text in a polygon or other text region.)

Comment: I checked the [Collins thesaurus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus), and did an on-line search.  The search returned documentation for several programs (such as Microsoft SmartArt) that have very distinct "Outline" versus "Fill" commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first stab at an answer:

> Fill Completely...

This neatly fits in alphabetical order after "Border..." and "Fill...", and before "Pen...".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/45158)

Comment: @Mayo -- This answer is a solution to the problem.  Unless other users post better answers, the original poster is likely to use this answer to solve his problem.  By the way, I can ask the original poster any questions I want off-line.  (And the original poster doesn't really need to write in the third person.…)

Answer (score 0):

"Fill+Border" or "Border+Fill"

It's a tool menu, clarity trumps cleverness.  This is even actually shorter than your suggested answer.

I would similarly advise changing "pen" to "text."  Not only is it more direct, but it will save users confusion over how most drawing programs use "pen" to refer to a tools that creates lines and strokes.